# Exporting data files - which pattern to use

Tags: design-patterns, export

I'm going to implement a data export system (downloading files from a website). The system shall provide following things:

- different data formats: xls, csv, etc.
- different report types (basic report, advanced report, report detailed on xxx,yyy, etc.)
- different time concerning the data
- different user accounts

Which design pattern shall be used for such system? I was thinking about Abstract Factory, Factory Method and Builder patterns, but I'm not sure which one suits better here. I'd appreciate short explanation or simple model structure.

Answer (score 1):

You don't pick a design pattern for a system; you pick a design pattern for a particular design problem *within* a system. Furthermore, sometimes it's even better to not try to force something to be a certain design pattern. If you follow good [OOP](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/10-object-oriented-design-principles.html) principles and [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29), design patterns will naturally emerge from your code.

From the requirements listed above, you really want to design the *system* first. After that, once you start needing to write code, you can consider design patterns for specific problems. An example might be that you need to perform the same action on different types of data. For that, you'd use polymorphism. And if you need to check various types and have only one type perform some action, at that point you might consider something like the Chain of Responsibility design pattern.

But you're not there yet, at least not with the slim requirements in your question.